# How to move images with relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, css-position, move

I have a webpage where I have the parent div with relative positioning, and all text with absolute positioning. I have now noticed that I cannot move around the image at all. What should I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/uchn0m5k/1/

I want the image to be behind (in terms of Z Space) the text, but as I want to add more images, I do not wish to set it as the background image:)

```css
.button {
  background-color: #08aabe;
  border: none;
  color: #faead3;
  padding: 0.2em 0.65em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  margin-left: 5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Top left text */

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  color: #08aabe;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

#squiggle {
  right: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="squiggle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" style=" height:30%;">

  <div class="top-left">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
    <a class="button" href="#">Button to clcik</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `z-index`? And FYI, modern browsers can support multiple background images nowadays.

Comment: No browser has needed any of those vendor prefixes in many years so you can remove them unless you need to support IE9 and lower. Then you can include the ms- ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do like this?

```css
.button {
    background-color: #08aabe;
    border: none;
    color: #faead3;
    padding: 0.2em 0.65em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.3vw;
    margin-left: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  user-drag: none;
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}



/* Top left text */
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-left h1{
  margin:0px;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  color: #08aabe;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;

}

body{
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color:black;

}

#squiggle{
  position:absolute;
  left: 22vw;
  top: 29px;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="squiggle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"  style=" height:30%;">

  <div class="top-left">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
    <a class="button"href="#">Button to clcik</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

You can view this [codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/PxmWJY).

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 5em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  left: 4em;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1.logo-text {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png">
  </div>
  <h1 class="logo-text">Lorem Ipsum</h1>  
</div>
```

Comment: I want to move the image behind the text

Answer (score 1):

So, I ***think*** this is what you're asking for? I switched up the CSS and basically added z-indexes to the "container", "img" and "top-left" elements, which moved the image of the dice behind the "top-left" container.

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 120px;
    left: 40px;
    user-drag: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
    z-index: -3;
}



/* Top left text */
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this answers your question. If not, please let me know and I'd be happy to try to figure out a better solution!

Comment: I think you're on your way to a solution, but you don't need the vendor prefixes you used. Not anymore anyway.

Comment: That is correct. I only included them because the OP had them included in his original CSS.